# Convert all content in a ScrollView to a bitmap?

Tags: java, android, uiscrollview, screenshot

I try to take a convert my `ScrollView` into `bitmap`, my `ScrollView` has content that spills out of the screen (hence scrolling made possible), after I [Ask here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25518449/android-taking-a-screenshoot-for-all-view-in-scrollview) I can capture my Activity in `ScrollView`, But I got A problem, the `Bitmap` for saving a Screenshot not create All View, only the last of `ScrollView`, and the rest of it is Black screen as Below :
[image]

this is my code for taking a Screenshot for all view in `ScrollView`:

```
 scroll_pp=(ScrollView)polis.findViewById(R.id.scroll_pp);
   utktest=polis.findViewById(R.id.scroll_pp);             
   int totalHeight = scroll_pp.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
   int totalWidth = scroll_pp.getChildAt(0).getWidth();
   Bitmap b= MethodSupport.loadBitmapFromView(utktest, totalWidth, totalHeight);

 String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +   File.separator + "Folder";
                    String fileName = "Test.jpg";
                    File myPath = new File(extr, fileName);
                    FileOutputStream fos = null;
                    try {
                        fos = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
                        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
                        fos.flush();
                        fos.close();
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(), b, "Screen", "screen");
                    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v, int width, int height) {
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width , height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);                
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        v.draw(c);
        return b;
    }
```

So Is there something wrong with my code so I can not display the `bitmap` in according what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `get First children of ScrollView` and `convert it to Bitmap`.

**Example:**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlChildContainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

You should try to load bitmap only when screen is loaded and layout is drawn, don't do it from onCreate method of Activity.

Comment: What do you mean by load bitmap when screen is loaded and layout is drawn. I just want to ask where to get first child of ScrollView.

Comment: Thank you was struggling with this for an hour. I didn't realize I should take scrollview child.